# Predicting from the middle of a Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to develop an auto-encoder for compressing images using Keras. I was able to train it and to compress images, but I am struggling with the decoder part of it. Specifically, given a compressed image, I don't know how to use the model to de-compress it.

This is what I have:

```
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
    code_layer = build_encoder(input_layer, size_of_code)  # add some convolution layers and max-pooling
    output_layer = build_decoder(code_layer)  # add some convolution layers and up-sampling

    autoencoder_model = keras.models.Model(input_layer, output_layer)
    encoder_model = keras.models.Model(input_layer, code_layer)
    decoder_model = ??
    autoencoder_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

using the code above I can train the `autoencoder_model` and compress the images using the `encoder_model`, but I don't know how to construct the `decoder_model`, mainly because I don't know how to insert a new input to the middle of the model.

Answer (score 2):

Like this. Instead of the code_layer, need to define an input layer and build the decoder model with that input.

```
latent_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(size_of_code))
output_layer = build_decoder(latent_inputs)  # add some convolution layers and up-sampling
decoder_model = keras.models.Model(latent_inputs, output_layer)
```

You can refer this complete VAE example:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py